# delayed_job vs cron for long-running tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, delayed-job

Each `Thing` inserted into the database has an `archive` attribute. When set to 0, nothing will happen. However, if it is not, I want it to be added to a queue to be processed.

Archiving a `Thing` can take anywhere from 3 to 30 seconds, because a lot of requests are sent and handled. So my question is do I make it so:

1. When a `Thing` has `archive` set to 1, have it put in a queue to be processed by a Rake task every so often (every 15 minutes or so), and then have the `archive` attribute set to 2, to stop it from being processed again
2. Make a `do_archive` method on `Thing`, and when saving, do `self.delay.do_archive`, and let `delayed_job` handle all of that for me

Some `Things` do not need to be processed, and the archiving isn't a time-essential thing. My gut is that `delayed_job` is probably a better idea, as it's not time-specific and just goes through a queue as opposed to running a script every day at midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you pretty much nailed it in your last paragraph. If it's something that is time dependent and not event driven, then cron makes more sense. But if there is an event that occurs and can queue it up, and it is not time dependent, then use a background job.

One thing you might want to consider is whether an actual messaging system makes more sense. While something like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) might be overkill for where you are today, there are other simpler options. [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) are two popular options that give you quite a bit more control over the background jobs and offer the simplicity of delayed_job and the robustness of a messaging system.